# How can we transpose every n rows to column in spark scala as shown like below

Tags: python, scala, apache-spark

Read delimited or fixed width format file as shown in below input format and want the output result in transpose format as shown in output format below. I tried pivot function, but not able to get expected output format.

Input:

```
**Col1, Col2, Col3, Col4**
   a    b     c     d
   e    f     a     e
   x    y     z     1
   2b         3     2
   xx   yy          zz
   t    u     v     z
```

Output:

```
**Col1, Col2, Col3, Col4, Col5, Col6, Col7, Col8**
   a    b     c     d     e     f     a     e
   x    y     z     a     2b          3     2
   xx   yy          zz    t     u     v     z
```

Comment: Can you please show the code that you have tried as the input and output does not give clear picture of what needs to be done?

Comment: if you go with the definition of transpose your output does not seems relevant.

Comment: This is code that I have tried -  for line in lns:
        if i == 1:
            f2.write(line.rstrip())
        else:
            f2.write(delimiter+line.rstrip())
        if i == int(combine):
            f2.write('\n')
            i = 1
        else:
            i += 1
    f2.close()

Answer (score 0):

There is no straight forward way of doing it. I am getting the required output as below and might not be the most efficient way but it works as per your output requirement.

```
//creating Test data
val df = Seq(("a","b","c","d"),("e","f","a","e"),("x","y","z","1"),("2b","","3","2"),("xx","yy","","zz"),("t","u","v","z")).toDF("col1","col2","col3","col4")
//adding an index column to keep track of the row index
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
val df1 = df.withColumn("id",monotonically_increasing_id + 1 )
//creating a window to get the order by id column
val w = org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.Window.orderBy("id")  
//using the lead function on the columns that we are adding to get the required output
val testDf = df1.withColumn("col5", lead("col1", 1, 0).over(w))
.withColumn("col6", lead("col2", 1, 0).over(w))
.withColumn("col7", lead("col3", 1, 0).over(w))
.withColumn("col8", lead("col4", 1, 0).over(w))
.filter("id%2 == 0").drop("id")
display(testDf)
```

you can see the output as below :

[image]